# FacetWP map change map-markers based on facet selection

Tags: wordpress, facetwp

At the moment I'm working on a project with WordPress, FacetWP and the map facet (that comes with FacetWP). I made a custom marker to show on the map like this:

```
// Custom markers for Map
add_filter( 'facetwp_map_marker_args', function( $args, $post_id ) {

  $markerUrl = get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/img/dealer-pin.png';

  $args['icon'] = array(
    'url' => $markerUrl,
    'scaledSize' => array(
      'width' => 23,
      'height' => 30
    )
  );
  return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

But I would like to change the markerURL based on another facet choice. 
Unfortunately I don't know how to get the other facet value inside this filter. I tried something like this (but this doesn't work):

```
// Custom markers for Map
add_filter( 'facetwp_map_marker_args', function( $args, $post_id ) {

  if( 'bezoekertype' == $args['facet']['name'] ) {
    if( $args['facet']['values'] == 'toon-bij-zakelijk' ) {
      return $markerUrl = get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/img/dealer-pin-2.png';
    } else {
      return $markerUrl = get_bloginfo('template_url') . '/img/dealer-pin.png';
    }
  }

  $args['icon'] = array(
    'url' => $markerUrl,
    'scaledSize' => array(
      'width' => 23,
      'height' => 30
    )
  );
  return $args;
}, 10, 2 );
```

If anybody could help this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

```
add_filter( 'facetwp_map_marker_args', function( $args, $post_id ) {
    $terms = wp_get_post_terms( $post_id, 'category' ); 

    foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
        if ( 'premium' == $term->slug ) {
            $args['icon'] = 'image1.png';
        }
        else {
            $args['icon'] = 'image2.png';
        }

    }
```